# how to manage the SSL3 “POODLE” Vulnerability

Tags: ssl

can someone explain how we should manage the SSL3 “POODLE” Vulnerability for our stores? If I turn-off the https in the config, isn't that making my checkout process appear 'unsecure'.

So, what's the solution/best workaround for a shop owner right now?

Thanks

note: as you can tell me the phrasing of my question, this comes from someone with very little technically knowledge in this area! Thanks for answering appropriately.

Comment: This is a web server admin question. It is about SSL/TLS protocols and has been answered [many times over in serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/search?q=poodle). Basically, if you're using a hosting provider, it's their problem. If you're running your own server or VPS, then you need to configure apache/nginx/? to not use that particular protcol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read to disable SSL, they do not mean you must disable HTTPS.

HTTPS is not SSL.

HTTPS tells the browser that it needs to make the connection via a secure protocol layer.
SSL is the protocol layer used to make the connection between your client machine and the server

SSL is just one of the protocols available.

TLS is the current standard (I think) which replaced SSL

Read: https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/10/15/poodle-a-ssl3-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566/

Answer (score 1):

Disable SSL v3 - that is all that is required.

Comment: OK, but is that something done on the magento backend or by the server administrator? I've mailed the hosting company, so I'll see what they say. I just want to be sure I've got everything covered. THanks.

Comment: It is done on the server, not magento

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your /etc/apache/sites-available/default-ssl.conf file:

SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3

Run: sudo apache2ctl configtest

End with: sudo service apache2 restart

Done.

Answer (score 0):

To neutralize POODLE, follow this post: [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/640589/httpd-wont-start-with-updated-sslciphersuite-poodle/640605#640605) or [that](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/security-patches/disabling-sslv3-for-poodle).

Essentially, you need to make a web server configuration change, which is done by modifying the SSL configuration file located at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`, `/etc/apache/...` or somewhere else. You can google for your specific platform where the SSL configuration file resides.

Identify the line for `SSLProtocol` and place it with:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

That's it!